# Best way to do validation

Tags: php

Just wondering how do i validate text in php?

I have a form on a website and the user can input text, however one of the fields requires the input to be hardware or software, but im wondering how do i make it so that if the user enters anything apart from that that it wont work?

Comment: This is very open. Can you provide some examples of what is and isn't valid? You could use a regex. Also, if you want it not to submit when invalid you'll need to do that client side JS (or AJAX (js to php)).

Comment: If you expect a specific input, be so kind as to give it to the user (eg via dropdown, radiobuttons or checkboxes)

Comment: You can use the `pattern` attribute in the input element, front-end javascript validation, back-end validation with feedback using messages, etc. lots of possibilities. Each with their own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @kingkero dropdown/radiobutton values can still be altered - you should mention this.

Answer (score 1):

Your can try simple php,

```
$input="hardware"; //user inputted text
if($input=='software' || $input=='hardware'){
  echo "Secure Enough";
 #proceed with other codes
}else{
 echo "Not valid";
 # not valid so do what ever you want to do
}
```

OR

with `regex`

```
$re = "/^(software|hardware)$/"; 
$str = "software"; 

if (preg_match($re, $str))
{
    echo 'Secure Enough';
}else{
    echo "Not valid";
}
```

**EDIT:**

OR

```
 if( in_array(strtolower($input), array("software", "hardware")) ) {
       echo "Secure Enough";
 } else {
       echo "Not Valid"; 
 }
```

**@courtesy** [ʰᵈˑ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000179/%CA%B0%E1%B5%88%CB%91)

Comment: **OR** `if( in_array(strtolower($input), array("software", "hardware")) ) {}`. Also, you're missing anchors on your regular expression. `/^(software|hardware)$/`

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ has the "better" solution for multiple string comparisons.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `m` flag on your regular expression. It means multi-line, and users won't be inputting more than 1 line (ie: `hardware\r\nsoftware`).

Comment: @gordoncarroll , yap, i have updated my answer

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ, ok that was just a demonstration.

Comment: Fix it up, and I'll upvote you. (It's a valid answer then) - [include the anchors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654501/best-way-to-do-validation#comment47450223_29654919) This will match the full string and not partial.